# What type of Central Arkansas weed is this?

Tags: identification

I live in Central Arkansas near Little Rock and have this weed I would like to identify.  The veins in the leaves stand out more than the picture shows.

[image]

Comment: I have seen this growing in my own yard (New York State). It is a woodland ground weed - grows in shaded areas. Leaves sort of looks like mustard leaves.  Do you have any more information?

Answer (score 1):

I finally identified the plant today. The plant in your photo is commonly known as "**White Avens**". It is a herbaceous, perennial wildflower that is widespread in many regions of the United States and Canada. The scientific name is "***Geum cadense***". It is a woodland **wildflower of the Rose family (Rosaceae)**.

I live in upstate NY. I knew I had this plant growing in my yard, so I have been waiting until now (mid-June) for it to bloom for identification. The immature plant form looks quite different during the late fall and early spring seasons with ground hugging rosettes of mottled (veined) leaves as shown in your photo. I have often noticed them as well. This "rosette leaf form" will eventually bolt in the spring and will mature to bloom in early summer. As they grow, the leaves take on a bright green color. Here are a couple of links with more information.

https://anps.org/2016/01/15/know-your-natives-white-avens/

https://www.illinoiswildflowers.info/savanna/plants/white_avens.htm